# Convert Message Author ID to string Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a simple discord bot that notifies users when someone says their nickname in a message. Whenever I try to convert the author id to a string in order to store it, I come across this error:

I've tried using simple ways such as str(authorid) and str(message.author.id) but thats the extent of what I know in Python

```
   authornick = message.author.nick
   f = open("notify.txt", "a")
   f.write("\n" + authorid + ":" + authornick)
   f.close()
   await message.channel.send("You have been added to the notify list.")
```

I want the output of this to convert the authorid to a string so it's able to write it to a text file, but it fails at converting it to a string. The error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Comment: could you provide a full example here? it looks like your way of retrieving the authorid doesnt work, but you dont show how you do it.

Comment: yea, at the top line there i was doing authornick = str(message.author.nick)

Comment: Please update your code to include an example that can be run on it's own. For example, currently it isn't known where `message` comes from, so it's impossible to know if `authornick = message.author.nick` will work.